# How to pass timestamp based dynamic parameter to a URL in h:outputLink?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I need to call a third party application from my JSF page, which will return an HTML content. The HTML content would then be displayed on the pop-up window.

The third-party URL is a GET service which expects a key based on the current unix time-stamp. So I can generate the complete request URL only when the user clicks on the hyperlink otherwise the key would already be invalid (Key is valid for 5 minutes only)

I tried the below option, but in this case the key is generated when the page is rendered and if the user clicks on the hyperlink after 5 mintues the link is invalid.

Also, as this is the authentication key generation process, I do not want to do this in the javascript due to security reasons.

```
<h:outputLink onclick="window.open('#{testMBean.thirdpartylink}','ThirdParty','menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, toolbar=no, location=yes'); return false; ">
link number
</h:outputLink>
```

I tried this as well, but its the same behavior

```
<h:outputLink onclick="#{indexBean.JSPopup()}">#{indexBean.linkName}</h:outputLink>

public String JSPopup() {
    return "javascript:void window.open('" + getRedirectLink() + "','" + linkName + "','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;";
}
```

Can you please provide some input, how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This will call an actual generated url:

```
    <h:panelGroup id="linkBlk">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function openIt() {
                var url='#{indexBean.theLink}';
                window.open(url);
            }
        </script>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <p:commandButton value="get PopUp" ajax="true" partialSubmit="true" process="@this" update="linkBlk" actionListener="#{indexBean.buildLink()}" oncomplete="openIt()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will try this approach.